# Android Studio 2.2 doesn't generate R.java

Tags: android-studio, r.java-file

I can't create new projects anymore with this problem now despite my version is the latest 2.2.

Whenever I create a new project I get this message from gradle build:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

Comment: Try `Invalidate Cache & Restart` by choosing `File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart` after restarting try to `Clean & Build` your project.

Comment: I am facing this too. Also it sometimes picks up any random library's R.java.

Answer (score 0):

PROPLEM SOLVED:
android studio was notifying me of new updates to be installed and i made sure to check all (android SDK build tools) in tools packages folder in SDK manager